# Accessing out-of-scope methods for unit testing purposes

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, zepto

Because I'm using the Zepto JavaScript library, all of my application code has to be wrapped inside a function called Zepto. This was not a problem until recently, when I tried to write unit tests. I realized that I can't access my API because it is inside the scope of that function.

Here's what my main JS file looks like:

```
Zepto(function(){
    var MyAPI = (function(){
        function myMethod() {
        ....
        }
        return {
            myMethod: myMethod
        }
    })(); 

    MyAPI.myMethod(); // works correctly
});
```

Here's what my unit testing file looks like (I'm using Qunit):

```
// include my main JS file 

test( 'MyAPI unit test', function() {
    // The test obviously fails because MyAPI is outside of scope
    ok( typeof MyAPI.myMethod === 'function', 'MyAPI is available' );
});
```

So, my question is, how do I write unit tests for an API that has to be encapsulated within that Zepto function? In other words, how can I make the methods available outside of that function context so they can be tested?

Comment: Wouldn't you do it the same way you would normally call the functions?

Comment: MyAPI is not accessible in global scope because it was defined within the Zepto function.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by storing certain methods inside a global variable. This provided the best of both worlds, allowing me to access the functionality of Zepto while referring to the methods outside of the Zepto function.

Updated main JS file:

```
var app = {}; 

Zepto(function(){
    app.MyAPI = (function(){
        function myMethod() {
        ....
        }
        return {
            myMethod: myMethod
        }
    })(); 

    app.MyAPI.myMethod(); // works correctly
});
```

Updated test suite file:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    test( 'MyAPI unit test', function() {
        // The test now works because MyAPI is stored in the global 'app'
        ok( typeof app.MyAPI.myMethod === 'function', 'MyAPI is available' );
    }); 

}, 3000); // Give Zepto time to instantiate
```